# imshow img with values 0 1 with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, imshow

I have a mat of this type

```
Mat port(M.size(),CV_8UC1);
```

and inside I have the 2 values: ​​0 and 1.

If I try to do `imshow ( " p " , port) ;`
img by a black .

How can I distinguish all 0 and 1 with two different colors ?

I tried and tried to use `line()` but you must already know the two closest points while I do not know what the values ​​1 distanced from each other .
someone can help me ?
It seems a trivial problem

Comment: What do you have in your Mat? `0.1` as in `1/10`, or zero and one. How are you expecting colours in a single channel image `CV_8UC1` - it will be grayscale.

Answer (score 4):

Try scaling your data for display: `imshow(" p ", port*255);`

A gray value of `1` is almost indistinguishable from full black and will not be discernible on any normal monitor/screen. Scaling by 255 will make these pixels appear white.
Note that the scaling is done only for the display and do not affect the image itself.

Please see [the `imshow()` docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) for what scaling is done and the values for display:

> The function may scale the image, depending on its depth:
>
> - If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is.
> - If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255].
> - If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I can see very little of the " colored " line (not black ) that I would like . But I had to change the type of Mat with CV_32SC1 for other reasons

Comment: If your image type is `CV_8C1` as you wrote in your question, values of `1*255` should appear white. If your type is something else, you will need to check the documentation to see what scaling `imshow` does.

Comment: Yes, if your image is (still) `CV_32SC1` then `255*255` is the correct scaling factor.

Comment: @kea: Great :-). Please mark the answer as *answered*.